# Echad Ushmonim Umataym - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-one?

### ?אחד ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 281.

The lazy gematria on this one could be a splendid cure if you can't think of anything else.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period of the Book of Judges begins with Othneil and ends with Abdon therefore the book of Judges deals with **281**years, from the death of Joshua in 1350 BCE to the death of Abdon in 1069 BCE.

[Time line of the book of Judges](http://www.bible.ca/archeology/bible-archeology-exodus-route-date-chronology-of-judges.htm)

Comment: Does this analysis square with traditional Jewish sources?

Answer (score 4):

The [Venetian Jewish Ghetto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venetian_Ghetto) was in existence for [281 years (and 3 months)](http://www.jewishhistory.org.il/history.php?startyear=1790&endyear=1799) before [Napoleon Bonaparte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_Bonaparte) conquered the city and had the ghetto's gates torn down and burned.

---

Also, there were [281 Jewish soldiers in the Bavarian Army in 1906](http://books.google.com/books?id=60S1117Vb7MC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22281+jews%22&source=bl&ots=rf8s_X1RCc&sig=Ay15l_8JE3n_c7_CJn9Cr0d7iNk&hl=en&ei=eCzdTsSoEejKiQLrm4zcCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22281%20jews%22&f=false).

Also, there were 281 Jews with uncontested Italian citizenship who were [protected by the Italian Consul General during World War II](http://books.google.com/books?id=vUyKlrY98dwC&pg=PA747&lpg=PA747&dq=%22281+jews%22&source=bl&ots=N8oaaGyjNr&sig=HF7Idgw_6yONUbpj-m9sq0VEY9o&hl=en&ei=eCzdTsSoEejKiQLrm4zcCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=281&f=false)

Comment: There are other negative facts regarding groups of 281 Jews, so I have skipped them over.

Answer (score 1):

Antiochus I reigned from **281**-261 BCE

Happy Channukah!

Comment: True (or, at least, true according to Wikipedia), but note that that was *not* the Antiochus of the _Chanuka_ story.

Comment: True about Channukah, but I figured it was the start of the problem so why not!